# How to pass arguments to the metaclass from the class definition in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, metaclass

This is a Python 3.x version of the [How to pass arguments to the metaclass from the class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762231/how-to-pass-arguments-to-the-metaclass-from-the-class-definition) question, listed separately by request since the answer is significantly different from Python 2.x.

---

In Python 3.x, how do I pass arguments to a metaclass's `__prepare__`, `__new__`, and `__init__` functions so a class author can give input to the metaclass on how the class should be created?

As my use case, I'm using metaclasses to enable automatic registration of classes *and their subclasses* into PyYAML for loading/saving YAML files.  This involves some extra runtime logic not available in PyYAML's stock `YAMLObjectMetaClass`.  In addition, I want to allow class authors to optionally specify the tag/tag-format-template that PyYAML uses to represent the class and/or the function objects to use for construction and representation.  I've already figured out that I can't use a subclass of PyYAML's `YAMLObjectMetaClass` to accomplish this--"because we don't have access to the actual class object in `__new__`" according to my code comment--so I'm writing my own metaclass that wraps PyYAML's registration functions.

Ultimately, I want to do something along the lines of:

```
from myutil import MyYAMLObjectMetaClass

class MyClass(metaclass=MyYAMLObjectMetaClass):
    __metaclassArgs__ = ()
    __metaclassKargs__ = {"tag": "!MyClass"}
```

...where `__metaclassArgs__` and `__metaclassKargs__` would be arguments going to the `__prepare__`, `__new__`, and `__init__` methods of `MyYAMLObjectMetaClass` when the `MyClass` class object is getting created.

Of course, I could use the "reserved attribute names" approach listed in [the Python 2.x version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762231/how-to-pass-arguments-to-the-metaclass-from-the-class-definition), but I know there is a more elegant approach available.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After digging through Python's official documentation, I found that Python 3.x offers a native method of passing arguments to the metaclass, though not without its flaws.

Simply add additional keyword arguments to your class declaration:

```
class C(metaclass=MyMetaClass, myArg1=1, myArg2=2):
  pass
```

...and they get passed into your metaclass like so:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):

  @classmethod
  def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases, **kargs):
    #kargs = {"myArg1": 1, "myArg2": 2}
    return super().__prepare__(name, bases, **kargs)

  def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kargs):
    #kargs = {"myArg1": 1, "myArg2": 2}
    return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
    #DO NOT send "**kargs" to "type.__new__".  It won't catch them and
    #you'll get a "TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments" exception.

  def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, myArg1=7, **kargs):
    #myArg1 = 1  #Included as an example of capturing metaclass args as positional args.
    #kargs = {"myArg2": 2}
    super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
    #DO NOT send "**kargs" to "type.__init__" in Python 3.5 and older.  You'll get a
    #"TypeError: type.__init__() takes no keyword arguments" exception.
```

You have to leave `kargs` out of the call to `type.__new__` and `type.__init__` (Python 3.5 and older; see "UPDATE" below) or will get you a `TypeError` exception due to passing too many arguments.  This means that--when passing in metaclass arguments in this manner--we always have to implement `MyMetaClass.__new__` and `MyMetaClass.__init__` to keep our custom keyword arguments from reaching the base class `type.__new__` and `type.__init__` methods.  `type.__prepare__` seems to handle the extra keyword arguments gracefully (hence why I pass them through in the example, just in case there's some functionality I don't know about that relies on `**kargs`), so defining `type.__prepare__` is optional.

#### UPDATE

In Python 3.6, it appears `type` was adjusted and `type.__init__` can now handle extra keyword arguments gracefully.  You'll still need to define `type.__new__` (throws `TypeError: __init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments` exception).

## Breakdown

In Python 3, you specify a metaclass via keyword argument rather than class attribute:

```
class MyClass(metaclass=MyMetaClass):
  pass
```

This statement roughly translates to:

```
MyClass = metaclass(name, bases, **kargs)
```

...where `metaclass` is the value for the "metaclass" argument you passed in, `name` is the string name of your class (`'MyClass'`), `bases` is any base classes you passed in (a zero-length tuple `()` in this case), and `kargs` is any uncaptured keyword arguments (an empty `dict` `{}` in this case).

Breaking this down further, the statement roughly translates to:

```
namespace = metaclass.__prepare__(name, bases, **kargs)  #`metaclass` passed implicitly since it's a class method.
MyClass = metaclass.__new__(metaclass, name, bases, namespace, **kargs)
metaclass.__init__(MyClass, name, bases, namespace, **kargs)
```

...where `kargs` is always the `dict` of uncaptured keyword arguments we passed in to the class definition.

Breaking down the example I gave above:

```
class C(metaclass=MyMetaClass, myArg1=1, myArg2=2):
  pass
```

...roughly translates to:

```
namespace = MyMetaClass.__prepare__('C', (), myArg1=1, myArg2=2)
#namespace={'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'C'}
C = MyMetaClass.__new__(MyMetaClass, 'C', (), namespace, myArg1=1, myArg2=2)
MyMetaClass.__init__(C, 'C', (), namespace, myArg1=1, myArg2=2)
```

Most of this information came from [Python's Documentation on "Customizing Class Creation"](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).

Comment: _>In Python 3, you specify a metaclass via keyword argument rather than class attribute:_


This style is not backward compatible to python2, please see
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32713241/3285282

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @drhagen .  This reminds me why I wrote the mystery code comment "because we don't have access to the actual class object in `__new__`".  My original answer on the Python 2 version of this question has also been updated.

Comment: This answer explains very nicely the intricacies involved with using `kargs`. As of Python 3.11, `type.__init__` still does not handle extra keywords and the (derived) metaclass's `__init__` needs to handle and exclude those from the call made to `super().__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of the code from my answer to that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762231/python-metaclass-arguments) about metaclass arguments which has been updated so that it'll work in *both* Python 2 *and* 3. It essentially does the same thing that Benjamin Peterson's [six](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) module's [`with_metaclass()`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.with_metaclass) function does — which namely is to explicitly create a new base class using the desired metaclass on-the-fly, whenever needed and thereby avoiding errors due to the metaclass syntax differences between the two versions of Python (because the way to do that didn't change).

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pprint import pprint

class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, class_name, parents, attrs):
        if 'meta_args' in attrs:
            meta_args = attrs['meta_args']
            attrs['args'] = meta_args[0]
            attrs['to'] = meta_args[1]
            attrs['eggs'] = meta_args[2]
            del attrs['meta_args'] # clean up
        return type.__new__(cls, class_name, parents, attrs)

# Creates base class on-the-fly using syntax which is valid in both
# Python 2 and 3.
class MyClass(MyMetaClass("NewBaseClass", (object,), {})):
    meta_args = ['spam', 'and', 'eggs']

myobject = MyClass()

pprint(vars(MyClass))
print(myobject.args, myobject.to, myobject.eggs)
```

Output:

```
dict_proxy({'to': 'and', '__module__': '__main__', 'args': 'spam',
            'eggs': 'eggs', '__doc__': None})
spam and eggs
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Python 3, you specify a metaclass via keyword argument rather than class attribute:

It's worth to say, that this style is not backward compatible to python 2. If you want to support both python 2 and 3, you should use:

```
from six import with_metaclass
# or
from future.utils import with_metaclass

class Form(with_metaclass(MyMetaClass, object)):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, but this answer only demonstrates how to pass a metaclass in a cross-compatible way.  How are arguments to the metaclass handled with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way to pass arguments to a metaclass in Python 3:

## Python 3.x

```
class MyMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, custom_arg='default'):
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)

        print('Argument is:', custom_arg)


class ExampleClass(metaclass=MyMetaclass, custom_arg='something'):
    pass
```

You can also create a base class for metaclasses that only use `__init__` with extra arguments:

```
class ArgMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)


class MyMetaclass(ArgMetaclass):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, custom_arg='default'):
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)

        print('Argument:', custom_arg)


class ExampleClass(metaclass=MyMetaclass, custom_arg='something'):
    pass
```