# What is this table=True inside a subclass of SQLModel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, sqlmodel

Consider this code:

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field

class Task(SQLModel, table=True):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
```

I only stepped away from python for a few weeks and now there are arguments in the class-inheritance brackets?  What does this do, how do I do it and are there drawbacks/benefits? Whats it called? Once I know what its called I can look it up.

EDIT: This is not a typo, this code works as is.

Comment: If you want to use as arguments, you should use as `task = Task(table=True)`

Comment: This code works as is and I just want to know why and how to make a class that does it.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762231/how-to-pass-arguments-to-the-metaclass-from-the-class-definition

Comment: nice thanks @JavohirElmurodov! Found this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400284/understanding-init-subclass

Comment: In this case it really is the metaclass though, as @JavohirElmurodov suggested. The `table` keyword argument is first picked up by `SQLModelMetaclass.__new__` [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/blob/0.0.8/sqlmodel/main.py#L288) and then assigned to the new class' `__config__` attribute. It is then later used during the metaclass' `__init__` and even later in the actual class `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

`table=True` is the attribute that the class SQLModel uses to distinguish if something is a Pydantic model or an SQLAlchemy model.

### Long answer

Not that long .. but here is the [class](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/blob/main/sqlmodel/main.py#L474) and [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/blob/main/sqlmodel/main.py#L545) is where the check happens. There is more to it, but basically, it is to distinguish if it should be a Pydantic model or an SQLAlchemy model.

Comment: Im not  sure, but If I did this: `class MyClass(someVar=True): ... `  How do I access `someVar` from within the class? Can it even be done?  What is this even called and how do I find out more?

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like (from your second link) its in the `cls.__config__`   where `cls` is used instead of `self`

Comment: `getattr(cls.__config__, "someVar")`

Comment: found it , its part of __init_subclass__   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400284/understanding-init-subclass

Comment: Does the above answer, answer your question about `table=True`?

Comment: Technically, the code passages you linked do not show, where the keyword argument is actually picked up. This happens in the metaclass' `__new__` method, as soon as the subclass created. But the explanation of the purpose is correct.