# How do I call a class function inside the class definition?

Tags: python, class, oop, class-method, class-members

```py
class MetaData():

    maxSize = 2**10

    # class definition code
    if not os.path.exists('sample.data'):
        SSD  = open('sample.data', 'wb+')
        data = {
            0: [],
            1: {'.': None,}
        }
        data[1]['~'] = data[1]

        MetaData.save()  # i want to call the save function here


    # class function
    @classmethod
    def save(cls):

        cls.SSD.seek(0)
        cls.SSD.write(b' ' * cls.maxSize)
        cls.SSD.seek(0)
        cls.SSD.write(pickle.dumps(cls.data))
```

I want to use the `save()` function inside the class block. I've tried `MetaDate.save()` and simply `save()` both of which throw errors

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Edit**

Yes, `maxSize` is a class var and yes i can access it using `cls.maxSize`.

Comment: Also, `SSD` isn't a member, so `cls.SSD` won't work.

Comment: It also isn't a class function, its an instance function where the commonly referred to parameter of `self` has been renamed

Comment: In order to make a function a class function, you should add the decorator @classmethod, but still your code won't work

Comment: Unless you actually need a class for some reason, you probably want something closer to just [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/7ab17e7cb0baeed74489901374195ea4)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very similar to one I asked once — [Calling class staticmethod within the class body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body) — which is interesting because it means you could make it a static method instead and call it like this:

```
import os
import pickle


class MetaData:
    maxSize = 2**10

    @staticmethod
    def save():
        SSD.seek(0)
        SSD.write(b' ' * cls.maxSize)
        SSD.seek(0)
        SSD.write(pickle.dumps(cls.data))

    # class definition code
    if not os.path.exists('sample.data'):
        SSD  = open('sample.data', 'wb+')
        data = {
            0: [],
            1: {'.': None,}
        }
        data[1]['~'] = data[1]

        save.__func__()  # Call the save function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer.

You can use a metaclass to workaround to the limitation that you can't reference the class in the class body (since the class doesn't exist yet). You can create the class in the metaclass `__new__()` method and then modify it — in this case by calling a classmethod defined in it. Here's what I mean:

```
import os
import pickle


class MetaMetaData(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classdict):

        cls = type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, classdict)

        if not os.path.exists('sample.data'):
            cls.SSD = open('sample.data', 'wb+')

            cls.data = data = {
                0: [],
                1: {'.': None,}
            }
            data[1]['~'] = data[1]

            cls.save()

        return cls


class MetaData(metaclass=MetaMetaData):
    maxSize = 2**10

    @classmethod
    def save(cls):
        cls.SSD.seek(0)
        cls.SSD.write(b' ' * cls.maxSize)
        cls.SSD.seek(0)
        cls.SSD.write(pickle.dumps(cls.data))

    # class definition code
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(MetaData.data)
```

Output produced from running it for the first time (i.e. when there was no preexisting `sample.data` file):

```
{0: [], 1: {'.': None, '~': {...}}}
```

Note that the `SSD` class attribute is an open file — which is very strange, but that's what your code would do too, if it were runnable.

Answer (score -1):

At the point when  you call `save`, the class is not yet defined. One way to get around this is to use inheritance and define `save` in the base-class:

```
class B:
    @classmethod
    def save(cls):
        print("Saving")

class A(B):
    B.save()
```

Then of course, variables in the head of `A` are not known in `B.save` and have to be given as arguments to `save`.

Well, or like this:

```
class B:
    SSD = None

    @classmethod
    def save(cls):
        print(f"Saving {cls.SSD}")

class A(B):
    B.SSD = 3.14

    B.save()
```

Comment: Why do you need a separate class for this? Just put `B.save()` after the class definition, done.

Comment: true, @deceze, Thinking about it, I would normally avoid any code (other than simple assignments of static variables) in the class header, then put all that logic e.g. into a class method, and as you say, call it afterwards to complete the initialisation. ... or overthink the design and avoid too much of this static stuff alltogether.