# python function type comment

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to know Python type comment for function argument.

I already know basic type comment. (int, str, list, dict ... etc ...)

but. I don't know how to Custom Class type comment in This Class

ex)

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, score:int):
        self.score = score
    def compare_score(self, another_student: Student):
        return 1 if self.score > another_student.score else 0 if self.score == another_student.score else -1
```

this situation. receive an error message => Unresolved reference 'Student'

plz help.

Comment: Custom class type as in forward referencing or you want operator overloading for comparison operators? check about forward referencing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035423/how-to-refer-to-the-class-from-within-it-like-a-recursive-function

Comment: @SobyDamn type annotations are a special case here. I linked the appropriate canonical duplicate.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this is much better thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your using self class.
better you just create external function for this

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, score:int):
        self.score = score
        
def compare_score(self, another_student: Student):
        return 1 if self.score > another_student.score else 0 if self.score == another_student.score else -1
```

or just pass value you need to compare

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, score:int):
        self.score = score
    def compare_score(self, score:int):
        return 1 if self.score > score else 0 if self.score == score else -1
```

Comment: This example is Simple example.... I'm sorry for your misunderstanding.
and, I'm studing typing now. so function arguement change is not answer for me.(although This is wonderful Solution. Thank you)