# What's an example use case for a Python classmethod?

Tags: python, class, class-method

I've read [What are Class methods in Python for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-are-class-methods-in-python-for) but the examples in that post are complex.  I am looking for a clear, simple, bare-bones example of a particular use case for classmethods in Python.

Can you name a small, specific example use case where a Python classmethod would be the right tool for the job?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Class methods in Python for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-are-class-methods-in-python-for).

Comment: I've edited the question to explain the distinction between the two questions.  I am looking for a Hello World-type bare bones example use case.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Helper methods for initialization:

```
class MyStream(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filepath, ignore_comments=False):    
        with open(filepath, 'r') as fileobj:
            for obj in cls(fileobj, ignore_comments):
                yield obj

    @classmethod
    def from_socket(cls, socket, ignore_comments=False):
        raise NotImplemented # Placeholder until implemented

    def __init__(self, iterable, ignore_comments=False):
       ...
```

Comment: Indeed, providing alternate constructors is the classic use case for `classmethod`. Unlike their `staticmethod` equivalents, they play nicely with subclasses.

Answer (score 34):

Well `__new__` is a pretty important classmethod. It's where instances usually come from

so `dict()` calls `dict.__new__` of course, but there is another handy way to make dicts sometimes which is the classmethod `dict.fromkeys()`

eg.

```
>>> dict.fromkeys("12345")
{'1': None, '3': None, '2': None, '5': None, '4': None}
```

Comment: +1 for a good real-world example. Though you leave implicit the fact that `fromkeys` is also a classmethod.

Comment: Technically, `__new__` is implicitly turned into a static method. There is other machinery in the instance creation process that passes in the appropriate class object as the first argument. `dict.fromkeys` is an excellent example of an actual class method, though.

Comment: And, of course, `__new__` still relies on the same *concept* as `classmethod` even if it isn't actually implemented that way.

Answer (score 21):

The biggest reason for using a `@classmethod` is in an alternate constructor that is intended to be inherited.  This can be very useful in polymorphism. An example:

```
class Shape(object):
    # this is an abstract class that is primarily used for inheritance defaults
    # here is where you would define classmethods that can be overridden by inherited classes
    @classmethod
    def from_square(cls, square):
        # return a default instance of cls
        return cls()
```

Notice that `Shape` is an abstract class that defines a classmethod `from_square`, since `Shape` is not really defined, it does not really know how to derive itself from a `Square` so it simply returns a default instance of the class.

Inherited classes are then allowed to define their own versions of this method:

```
class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, side=10):
        self.side = side

    @classmethod
    def from_square(cls, square):
        return cls(side=square.side)


class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, length=10, width=10):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    @classmethod
    def from_square(cls, square):
        return cls(length=square.side, width=square.side)


class RightTriangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, a=10, b=10):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = ((a*a) + (b*b))**(.5)

    @classmethod
    def from_square(cls, square):
        return cls(a=square.length, b=square.width)


class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius=10):
        self.radius = radius

    @classmethod
    def from_square(cls, square):
        return cls(radius=square.length/2)
```

The usage allows you to treat all of these uninstantiated classes polymorphically

```
square = Square(3)
for polymorphic_class in (Square, Rectangle, RightTriangle, Circle):
    this_shape = polymorphic_class.from_square(square)
```

This is all fine and dandy you might say, but why couldn't I just use as `@staticmethod` to accomplish this same polymorphic behavior:

```
class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius=10):
        self.radius = radius

    @staticmethod
    def from_square(square):
        return Circle(radius=square.length/2)
```

The answer is that you could, but you do not get the benefits of inheritance because `Circle` has to be called out explicitly in the method.  Meaning if I call it from an inherited class without overriding, I would still get `Circle` every time.

Notice what is gained when I define another shape class that does not really have any custom from_square logic:

```
class Hexagon(Shape):
    def __init__(self, side=10):
        self.side = side

    # note the absence of classmethod here, this will use from_square it inherits from shape
```

Here you can leave the `@classmethod` undefined and it will use the logic from `Shape.from_square` while retaining who `cls` is and return the appropriate shape.

```
square = Square(3)
for polymorphic_class in (Square, Rectangle, RightTriangle, Circle, Hexagon):
    this_shape = polymorphic_class.from_square(square)
```

Comment: you have a typo in class RightTriangle. the init method should be "__init__" but you write it as "__init"

Comment: shouldn't the Initiation be like :                                                     
```square = Square(3)
rect = Rectangle(15,5)
 rt = RightTriangle(5,15)
 cir = Circle(50)

  for polymorphic_class in (rect,square,cir,rt):
    this_shape = polymorphic_class.from_square(polymorphic_class)
    print("Initating Class ",type(this_shape).__name__) ```

Comment: No @AlferdNobel, in your example you are instantiating the class prior to iterating on them.  When you instantiate a class it becomes an instance of that class and so `polymorphic_class` used as the iteration variable becomes a misnomer.  It is true that you can call a `classmethod` from an instance, but your code will be creating a total of 8 instances of different variations of `Shape` inherited classes, once prior to the `for` loop and then once again after where `this_shape = polymorphic_class.from_square(...)` instantiates an entirely new instance from attributes of the iterated instance.

Comment: Furthermore, @AlferdNobel, it will fail for many of those instances because in passing varying shapes as the arguments to `from_square` they will very likely not have the attributes that are expected, since this method expects the argument to be an instance of the `Square` class and your iterations will also include `Rectangles`, `Circles` and `RightTriangles`

Answer (score 20):

I don't know, something like named constructor methods?

```
class UniqueIdentifier(object):

    value = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def produce(cls):
        instance = cls(cls.value)
        cls.value += 1
        return instance

class FunkyUniqueIdentifier(UniqueIdentifier):

    @classmethod
    def produce(cls):
        instance = super(FunkyUniqueIdentifier, cls).produce()
        instance.name = "Funky %s" % instance.name
        return instance
```

Usage:

```
>>> x = UniqueIdentifier.produce()
>>> y = FunkyUniqueIdentifier.produce()
>>> x.name
0
>>> y.name
Funky 1
```

Answer (score 10):

I find that I most often use `@classmethod` to associate a piece of code with a class, to avoid creating a global function, for cases where I don't require an instance of the class to use the code.

For example, I might have a data structure which only considers a key valid if it conforms to some pattern.  I may want to use this from inside and outside of the class. However, I don't want to create yet another global function:

```
def foo_key_is_valid(key):
    # code for determining validity here
    return valid
```

I'd much rather group this code with the class it's associated with:

```
class Foo(object):

    @classmethod
    def is_valid(cls, key):
        # code for determining validity here
        return valid

    def add_key(self, key, val):
        if not Foo.is_valid(key):
            raise ValueError()
        ..

# lets me reuse that method without an instance, and signals that
# the code is closely-associated with the Foo class
Foo.is_valid('my key')
```

Comment: class methods can be called with either a class or an instance, so for example in `add_key` `Foo.is_valid(key)` _could_ also be `self.is_valid(key)` http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod

Comment: This use case sounds more like a static method than a class method. If your method isn't using the cls parameter than you should probably use @staticmethod instead.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful example of classmethod is in extending enumerated types. A classic Enum provides symbolic names which can be used later in the code for readability, grouping, type-safety, etc. This can be extended to add useful features using a classmethod. In the example below, Weekday is an enuerated type for the days of the week. It has been extended using classmethod so that instead of keeping track of the weekday ourselves, the enumerated type can extract the date and return the related enum member.

```py
from enum import Enum
from datetime import date


class Weekday(Enum):
    MONDAY = 1
    TUESDAY = 2
    WEDNESDAY = 3
    THURSDAY = 4
    FRIDAY = 5
    SATURDAY = 6
    SUNDAY = 7
    #
    @classmethod
    def from_date(cls, date):
        return cls(date.isoweekday())
```

```py
Weekday.from_date(date.today())     
<Weekday.TUESDAY: 2>
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html

Answer (score -5):

```
in class MyClass(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    obj=0
    x=classmethod
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.nom='lamaizi'
        self.prenom='anas'
        self.age=21
        self.ville='Casablanca'
if __name__:
    ob=MyClass()
    print(ob.nom)
    print(ob.prenom)
    print(ob.age)
    print(ob.ville)
```