# Python - AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python

I have 3 python files .

**MyModule.py**

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def hello(self):
        print('Hello ' + self.name)
```

**Loader.py**

```
import pickle
from MyModule import *

me = pickle.load(file('my_pkl.pickle','rb'))
me.hello()
```

**Dumper.py**

```
import pickle
from MyModule import *

me = MyClass('Anil')
pickle.dump(me, open('my_pkl.pickle','wb'))
```

When I exceute Loader.py I get below error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'name'
```

How can I access name instance vaiable?

Comment: Why is `me.hello()`?

Comment: @thinkerou I just want to call `hello()` method on `me` instance

Comment: But, the `me` and class `MyClass` does not matter.

Comment: Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738470/whats-an-example-use-case-for-a-python-classmethod) about `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a instance method as a class method. Make it an instance method.

```
# remove @classmethod decorator
# called on instance: me.hello()

def hello(self):
    print('Hello ' + self.name)
```