# Use of @classmethod in Python besides creating an alternate constructor

Tags: python, python-decorators

I was trying to think of use cases of the @classmethod special decorator besides creating an "overloaded" (I guess not really overloaded since the method name would be different from **init**) constructor, but couldn't think of any.

I've checked out posts like [What's an example use case for a Python classmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738470/whats-an-example-use-case-for-a-python-classmethod) but could only find use cases that point to the alternate constructor.

One other case I could think of was to couple a method with a class to encapsulate related logic (as mentioned by @samplebias in the post linked above), but I think @staticmethod is more suitable for enclosing related logic to a class (as someone commented on the post by @samplebias).

Could anyone help me identify some additional use cases for this special decorator?

Comment: I've only ever used it for alternate constructors. I've **never** used @staticmethod

Comment: If I have a base class and 4 subclasses inherit from base, I would like to modify the flow logic or change parts of it based on which subclass the method is called from. Then I need the (sub)class that this method is called from. Then I need classmethod.

Comment: Another use case might be to set default values for new instances (for example, for network-related stuff, you might want to set a default timeout, default host, etc). You could do that by setting attributes of the class, but if it's common to want to set several at once, a class method might be handy.

Comment: Hmm... So basically a case where we want to define a method that modifies class attributes? I think that makes sense as static methods are not really meant to alter the class?

Comment: Static methods *can't* alter the class, since they don't get a reference to it. (Well, they could via the class's name, but that would break inheritance.)

Comment: Ah I see... So maybe I just need to identify a context where the class object is being modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going through some material on OOP with Python and found a use case of the `@classmethod` decorator besides as an overloaded constructor.

It makes sense to use class methods when acting (altering) directly on the class object. For example, if you have an `Employee` object and `base_raise_factor` as a class variable, it would make sense to create a class method on Employee to alter this variable.

You could argue we could just set `Employee.base_raise_factor` to something directly, but I think it's better to adhere to `encapsulation` and not modify the internals directly. Plus, we could define some additional logic in the class method that updates `base_raise_factor`.