# Class error, using __new__ , instead of __init__, trying to return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

**Description**:

I am trying to return a value from a class when I call it.

I want the result of an object's method call upon creating the object.

I want to get the value of:

```py
A().get_result() 

# by just calling"
A()
```

**My Question**:

Why does `A.get_result()` require the argument `self`?

**Minimal Reproducible Example**:

Using the following class definition:

```py
class A():
    _arg_list = None
    
    def __new__(self, my_args):
        self._arg_list = my_args
        return self.get_result()
        
    def get_result(self):
        return self._args_list[0]
```

**Current Result**:

```
A(['arg1','arg2'])


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 A(['arg1','arg2'])

Cell In[5], line 9, in A.__new__(self, my_args)
      5 def __new__(self, my_args):
      7     self._arg_list = my_args
----> 9     return self.get_result()

TypeError: A.get_result() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

**Desired Result**:

```
A(['arg1','arg2'])
>> 'arg1'
```

Comment: Have you considered just making a function called `def A()`?

Comment: "using __new__ , instead of __init__" why would you do that?

Comment: Now that I understand how it would work, it think it's a great resource.

Comment: This [linked dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738470/whats-an-example-use-case-for-a-python-classmethod) isn't correct. While class methods might be a better fit for OP's problem, his question is about customizing `__new__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance methods operate on, well... instances. In Python, that's made explicit by requiring `self` as the first parameter of all instance methods (though the exact name can be anything, by convention, it's always `self` for instance_methods and `cls` for class methods). Other OO languages make this implicit (where `self` or `this` is just a magical keyword), but nonetheless require it.

Even if you don't want an object to hang around, and you just want to call the instance method `get_result()` once, you still need the instance call the method on. You have 2 options:

1. Change `get_result()` to not be an instance method (so it doesn't require an instance)
2. Create an instance to call `get_result()` on.

Here's one possible way to achieve this:

```py
class A():
    _arg_list = None
    
    def __new__(cls, my_args):
        new_instance = super().__new__(cls)
        new_instance._args_list = my_args
        
        return new_instance.get_result()
        
    def get_result(self):
        return self._args_list[0]

print(A(['arg1', 'arg2'])) # => 'arg1'
```

But really, this is all really weird. Unless you have a really good reason not to, I'd suggest:

1. Circumvent all this headache by just making a function, and getting rid of the class all together:

   ```py
   # You *could* call it A if you really wanted, but people would expect that to be a class, so don't do that.
   def a(my_args):
       return my_args[0]
   ```
2. Just use `A().get_result()`, which is perfectly clear.

Comment: You perfectly explained how that would work, and now I get it. My minimal example does not reflect the overall problem but just one concept that I was struggling with. I appreciate your explanation for that.

Comment: @JesseSealand Glad I could help! If I could suggest, when asking a question, you should give more insight into your real underlying issue. Otherwise there's a risk that people end up on a wild goose change to solve a problem for a solution approach that might not be the best approach to being with (and I'll be honest, I think it's **likely** that it isn't, in this case). See https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

Because **you defined it to require `self`**, as is normal for methods!

Perhaps the part you are missing is that the first argument to `__new__` is actually the *class*.

So

```
return self.get_result()
```

Is equivalent to:

```
return A.get_result()
```

And it is important to note, the implicit binding of the first argument only occurs when you call a method *on an instance*. You don't actually have an instance anywhere in your code!

But the question you really should be asking yourself here is why `A` is a class *at all*.

Comment: You're saying the argument and the methods are not bound to the class because the object is not yet created? That would make sense.

Comment: @JesseSealand bound to the **instance**. And just define your class `A` with just the `get_value` method, and do `A.get_value()` and you get the exact same error, because in your code, that is *exactly* what you are doing, `self` in `__new__` is `A`, not an instance of `A`, the job of `__new__` is to *create the instance*