# When should I use @classmethod and when def method(self)?

Tags: python, class-method, method-dispatch

While integrating a Django app I have not used before, I found two different ways to define functions inside the class. The author seems to use them both distinctively and intentionally. The first one is the one that I myself use a lot:

```
class Dummy(object):

    def some_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something here
        # self is the class instance
```

The other one is the one I never use, mostly because I do not understand when and what to use it for:

```
class Dummy(object):

    @classmethod
    def some_function(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something here
        # cls refers to what?
```

The `classmethod` decorator in the python documentation says:

> A class method receives the class as the implicit first argument, just
> like an instance method receives the instance.

So I guess `cls` refers to `Dummy` itself (the `class`, not the instance). I do not exactly understand why this exists, because I could always do this:

```
type(self).do_something_with_the_class
```

Is this just for the sake of clarity, or did I miss the most important part: spooky and fascinating things that couldn't be done without it?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Your guess is correct - you understand *how* `classmethod`s work.

The why is that these methods can be called both on an instance OR on the class (in both cases, the class object will be passed as the first argument):

```
class Dummy(object):

    @classmethod
    def some_function(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        print cls

#both of these will have exactly the same effect
Dummy.some_function()
Dummy().some_function()
```

**On the use of these on instances**: There are at least two main uses for calling a classmethod on an instance:

1. `self.some_function()` will call the version of `some_function` on the actual type of `self`, rather than the class in which that call happens to appear (and won't need attention if the class is renamed); and
2. In cases where `some_function` is necessary to implement some protocol, but is useful to call on the class object alone.

**The difference with `staticmethod`**: There is another way of defining methods that don't access instance data, called `staticmethod`. That creates a method which does not receive an implicit first argument at all; accordingly it won't be passed any information about the instance or class on which it was called.

```
In [6]: class Foo(object): some_static = staticmethod(lambda x: x+1)

In [7]: Foo.some_static(1)
Out[7]: 2

In [8]: Foo().some_static(1)
Out[8]: 2

In [9]: class Bar(Foo): some_static = staticmethod(lambda x: x*2)

In [10]: Bar.some_static(1)
Out[10]: 2

In [11]: Bar().some_static(1)
Out[11]: 2
```

The main use I've found for it is to adapt an existing function (which doesn't expect to receive a `self`) to be a method on a class (or object).

Comment: Nice one: I like the answer being split up into how - why. As far as i got it now @classmethod allows to access the function without the need for an instance. This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you.

Comment: I'd say calling class methods on instances is bad coding style - just no reason to do so and can only cause confusion. But yes it works (java allows the same thing, but issues a compile warning when calling static methods through instances)

Comment: @Voo What do you mean "no reason to do so"? It is necessary if the method performing the call expects the object to implement that method.

Comment: @Voo I think this is just for the sake of the explanation. No one sane would write 2 parantheses more if he had to :D

Comment: @marue It's frequently useful where some other code expects an object to implement a method, but the implementation does not require the instance, and in some other contexts you would want to call it on the class.

Comment: @marcin True duck typing does give it some other dimension. It was more about not writing things like `self.foo()` when it should be `Bar.foo()`.

Comment: @Marcin What do you mean with object in  "expects an object to implement a method"? An instance?

Comment: @marue Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @Voo Actually, `self.foo()` is preferable, because `self` may be an instance of a subclass which implements its own `foo`.

Comment: @Marcin I think this depends on what you want to achieve. But i get your point.

Comment: This answer *still* doesn't touch on the differences between `classmethod` and `staticmethod`, FWIW.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's true, but the question doesn't ask about `staticmethod`. I'll add something, though.

Comment: You should use a different lambda for `Bar`, as `1+1 == 2 == 1*2`, so it's impossible to tell from the results shown that `Bar().static_method` is actually called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-is-the-purpose-of-class-methods has a very good example

Comment: Just to add on this, let's say that there are two classes that inherit from class Animal called Dog and Cat, and there is a static method called `species_name()`.

If you want to create a method in Animal called `get_species_name()`, you would want to use the static methods not the instance methods and you would make it a static method.

Basically, I think it's when you only want to use static methods on child classes.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most common uses of `classmethod` in Python is factories, which are one of the most efficient methods to build an object. Because `classmethod`s, like `staticmethod`s, do not need the construction of a class instance. (But then if we use `staticmethod`,  we would have to hardcode the instance class name in the function)

This blog does a great job of explaining it:
https://iscinumpy.gitlab.io/post/factory-classmethods-in-python/

Comment: Why hardcoding the class name is a problem?

Answer (score -4):

If you add decorator @classmethod, That means you are going to make that method as static method of java or C++. ( static method is a **general term** I guess **;)** )
Python also has @staticmethod. and difference between classmethod and staticmethod is whether you can
access to class or static variable using argument or classname itself.

```
class TestMethod(object):
    cls_var = 1
    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        cls.cls_var += 1
        print cls.cls_var

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        TestMethod.cls_var += 1
        print TestMethod.cls_var
#call each method from class itself.
TestMethod.class_method()
TestMethod.static_method()

#construct instances
testMethodInst1 = TestMethod()    
testMethodInst2 = TestMethod()   

#call each method from instances
testMethodInst1.class_method()
testMethodInst2.static_method()
```

all those classes increase cls.cls_var by 1 and print it.

And every classes using same name on same scope or instances constructed with these class is going to share those methods.
There's only one TestMethod.cls_var 
and also there's only one TestMethod.class_method() , TestMethod.static_method()

And important question. why these method would be needed.

classmethod or staticmethod is useful when you make that class as a factory
or when you have to initialize your class only once. like open file once, and using feed method to read the file line by line.

Comment: (a) Static methods are something else; (b) classmethods are not shared by every class.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for letting me know my unclear definitions and all that.