# Why does this python method take self as a parameter

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Why does the "was_published_recently" method take self as a parameter? surely pub_date without the "self." would work fine

**Edited title for clarity**

Comment: also some good follow up reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984104/python-how-to-avoid-explicit-self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `pub_date` without the self would cause a NameError, as it would be referencing a local or global variable which doesn't exist.

`pub_date` is an attribute of the model instance, and can only be referenced via `self`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no class method in your listing, only an ordinary method.

In either case, python methods (other than `staticmethod`s) take a self parameter representing the object they are called on. Or to be more specific, the first parameter will be passed the self object, so you cannot decline to define a self parameter, only give it a different name.

More details on classmethods here: [When should I use @classmethod and when def method(self)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586787/when-should-i-use-classmethod-and-when-def-methodself/10586874#10586874)

Answer (score 0):

`self` changes the attribute of the instance of an object. If you want a class method, this cannot change or access the attributes of a specific variable. If pub_date does not change, then you can make it a class variable and add `@classmethod` above `was_published_recently`. Then, change the `self` to `cls`

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise classmethod was a thing of its own, I meant class method as in the method of this class.

Comment: Class method is basically an ordinary Python method except you have to call it like `Question.method()` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the method `was_published_recently()` without a `Question` instance i.e. `self`.

`pub_date` is a field of the model `Question` and without any model instance, it does not hold any `value` in it as it would just be a variable. You won't be able to get a value by calling the function `was_published_recently()` as it would not have the value of `pub_date` for performing the necessary computation.

So to call the method `was_published_recently()`, you will have to pass the instance to this method or directly call on an instance using `.` operator.