# Multiple ways to define a class method in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods

In Dive Into Python, Mark Pilgrim says that:

> When defining your class methods, you *must* explicitly list self as the first argument for each method

He then gives a few examples of this in code:

```
def clear(self): self.data.clear()
def copy(self):
    if self.__class__ is UserDict:
        return UserDict(self.data)
    import copy
    return copy.copy(self)
```

While going through some Python code online, I came across the `@classmethod` decorator. An example of that is:

```
class Logger:
    @classmethod
    def debug(msg):
        print "DEBUG: " + msg
```

(Notice that there is no `self` parameter in the `debug` function)

Is there any difference in defining class methods using `self` as the first parameter and using the `@classmethod` decorator? If not, is one way of defining class methods more commonly used/preferred over another?

Comment: `self` means reference to class instance.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-are-class-methods-in-python-for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@classmethod` isn't the same as defining an instance method. Functions defined with `@classmethod` receive the *class* as the first argument, as opposed to an instance method which receives a specific *instance*. See the Python docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! The sentence from the book makes a lot more sense now. I missed his point and thought he meant class methods (as in, static methods) where as he only meant methods defined inside a class. Hence, `self` is the reference to the instance of that class which obviously won't work when using `@classmethod` since you don't have an instance :)

Answer (score 0):

self is not and will never will be implicit.

"self will not become implicit.

Having self be explicit is a good thing. It makes the code clear by removing ambiguity about how a variable resolves. It also makes the difference between functions and methods small."

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3099/