# TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing Simulation of Round-Robbin algorithm and code listed below gives me error

```
RR.Przesuniecie[Oczekujace_procesy]
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is unsubscriptable
```

Here piece of code:

```
class RR:
 def Przesuniecie(self, Lista):
    if(len(Lista) < 2):
        return Lista
    else:
        head = Lista[0]

        for i in range(1, len(Lista)):
                Lista[i-1] = Lista[i]
        Lista[-1] = head

        return Lista

 def Symulacja(self, n ,kwant):
        Oczekujace_procesy = []

        [....]
        if(timer == kwant):
          RR.Przesuniecie[Oczekujace_procesy]
```

I have no idea why it gives me error. There just piece of code, on list `Oczekujace_procesy` I'm doing some operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method, `def Symulacja(self, n ,kwant):`, you are accessing `Przesuniecie` wrongly as `RR.Przesuniecie[Oczekujace_procesy]`.  `Przesuniecie` happens to be an instance method, and [not a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38276/1860929), so it isn't so accessible.

You can read about the differences between the two in [Difference between Class and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17134709/1860929).

Instead, access it as `self.Przesuniecie(Oczekujace_procesy)`

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation matters.

```
self.Przesuniecie(Oczekujace_procesy)
```