# call a static method or property in __init__ in python

Tags: python

I have many Questions !
look at this code plz:

```
class Dog(object):
    _the_most_oldest = int()

    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age=age


    @staticmethod   
    @property
    def the_most_oldest(age):
        if Dog._the_most_oldest < age:
            Dog._the_most_oldest=age
        return Dog._the_most_oldest
```

### 1 :

is it maybe that a property be a static method ??
beacuse I need a really static var that share between instances -> _the_most_oldest dog ! => so I need  @property . and because `the_most_oldest(age)` method is not for any special instance I need @staticmethod  !

### 2 :

the second thing I need to do is in every instace  the_most_oldest shuold be call and calculate and refresh _the_most_oldest var. how do that ?
this have Error :

```
def __init__(self,age):
    self.age=age
    the_most_oldest(self.age)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. In your place I would initialize `_the_most_oldest = 0` (and maybe call it `_the_oldest`, better english)
2. A `@staticmethod` in Python is just a function "contained in a class" in your case I think it would be better to use [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod).
3. If you want to assign a value to a property you can not use the decorator, you need to pass a setter and a getter method.

```
def _get_oldest(self):
        return self._the_oldest
```

`def _set_oldest(self, age):
    if Dog._the_oldest < age:
        Dog._the_oldest=age

the_oldest = property(_get_oldest, _set_oldest)`

Answer (score 3):

No, property can not be static method (it's not a method it's [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)).

Create class attribute which will hold all instances of that class.

```
class Dog(object):
    _dogs = []
```

And put new instances in the `_dogs` class attribute.

```
def __init__(self, age):
    self._dogs.append(self)
    self.age = age
```

And then create [classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-are-class-methods-in-python-for) `the_most_oldest`. Which will calculate the most oldest dog of all instances.

```
@classmethod
def the_most_oldest(cls):
    return max(cls._dogs, key=lambda dog: dog.age)
```