# How does unittest isolate attributes between tests?

Tags: python, python-unittest

If I run the following test case:

```py
class DummyTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.foo = 42
        super().setUpClass()

    def test_1(self):
        self.foo += 1
        print(f"=================> {self.foo}")

    def test_2(self):
        self.foo += 1
        print(f"=================> {self.foo}")
```

I get the following result:

```
tests/test_dummy.py::DummyTestCase::test_1 =================> 43
PASSED
tests/test_dummy.py::DummyTestCase::test_2 =================> 43
PASSED
```

How comes that I don't get `44` for the second test?

I understand that this would not be desirable for test isolation, but that would be what I would have expected if the test case behaved like a common class on which `self.foo += 1` is called twice. What implementation details in unittest make it behave like that?

Comment: What happens if you add a `print()` inside the `def setUpClass(cls):` method? How many times does that print?

Comment: @quamrana only once

Comment: hmm... TIL!  so `setUpClass` is called once per class, before creating any instances, then each test case is run in its own instance

Comment: @Anentropic no, it doesn't matter when it's called, it affects all existing instances. So long as the test methods are called *after it*, they will always see the value `42`.

Comment: @marco true, true

Comment: All answers are true, but I miss the simple fact mentioned that the correct way to write this would be `self.__class__.foo += 1` instead of `self.foo += 1`.

Answer (score 2):

A new `TestCase` instance is created before running each method, to achieve isolation between tests. This behavior is mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code):

> A new `TestCase` instance is created as a unique test fixture used to execute each individual test method.

The attribute you set in your setup code is a class attribute, and the assignment is done in a class method, `setUpClass`. **This method is only called once**, but in each test you set an *instance attribute* `self.foo` calculated from the value of the class attribute `DummyTestCase.foo` (which is set to 42 and never changed).

If you had used the `setUp` instance method instead, you'd get the same result, but under the hood the `setUp` method would be called twice, each time on a new instance, and set instance attribute `self.foo` to 42.

Here are some [remarks about instance and class attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) from the Python docs.

Comment: this contradicts the docs for `setUpClass` though https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures _"This will lead to setUpClass / setUpModule (etc) being called exactly once per class and module"_

Comment: @Anentropic both statements are true. `setUpClass` is a `@classmethod` so when it's called it changes the value of the `foo` for all existing instances.

Comment: I tried to provide more context about this in the answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

In short, `unittest` simply instantiates the class before every test. The `.setUpClass()` *class method* modifies the *class attribute* `foo`, which is then read by any instance that did not create its own *instance attribute* `foo`. See also [Difference between Class Attributes, Instance Attributes, and Instance Methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35520251/3889449).

The fact that `unittest` provides you with a base `TestCase` class to subclass is just for convenience. This is so you have access to everything you need on `self` and you can create multiple classes (one for each test category) with multiple methods (one for each test in the category). Without classes you would have to awkwardly manage a bunch of global functions or split different test categories into different modules. This class approach also allows to easily select and filter which test classes to run from command line.

See [Persist variable changes between tests in unittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21447740/3889449) for a method to keep a "state" between tests in the same test case class.

This example is exactly what happens in your case and could help clarify the confusion regarding *class* vs *instance* attributes:

```py
class C:
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.foo = 1

    def test_1(self):
        print(self.foo)
        self.foo = 2

    def test_2(self):
        print(self.foo)

c1 = C()
c2 = C()
C.setUpClass()
c1.test_1() # prints class attribute, then creates instance attribute
c2.test_2() # prints class attribute
c1.test_1() # prints instance attribute now
```

Output will be:

```
1
1
2
```

Comment: OK so basically one `TestCase` will be instanciated per test method, but for convenience we define multiple test methods on the same `TestCase` subclass. This is a bit tricky.

Comment: @Weier no. `TestCase` is instantiated once per test method. It's just that it doesn't matter because when `DummyTestCase.setUpClass()` is called it will set the *class attribute* `foo` and all the instances will see the value of `foo` as `42` since they didn't create an *instance attribute* `foo` theirselves.

Comment: In my piece of code, `self.foo += 1` also creates an instance attribute that would be incremented twice (`test_1` and `test_2`) if each test wasn't run in a dedicated instance.

Comment: @Weier yep that's true. If the class was only instantiated once you would see the second test print `43`.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of this behavior is in [`suite.py` line 114](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6b9122483f1f26afb0c41bd676f9754ffe726e18/Lib/unittest/suite.py#L114)

```
if _isnotsuite(test):
    self._tearDownPreviousClass(test, result)
    self._handleModuleFixture(test, result)
    self._handleClassSetUp(test, result)
    result._previousTestClass = test.__class__

    if (getattr(test.__class__, '_classSetupFailed', False) or
        getattr(result, '_moduleSetUpFailed', False)):
            continue
```

`_handleClassSetUp` is calling `setUpClass` if it is not `None`:

```
if setUpClass is not None:
    _call_if_exists(result, '_setupStdout')
    try:
        try:
            setUpClass()
        except:
            ...
```

As you can see, `setUpClass` is called for each test class in the test suite.

Comment: To be more precise, it's called once per test class (not once per test method): there is a [check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6b9122483f1f26afb0c41bd676f9754ffe726e18/Lib/unittest/suite.py#L145) in `_handleClassSetUp` that short-circuits if the test class is the same as before. Right after calling  `_handleClassSetUp` once, [`_previousTestClass` is set](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6b9122483f1f26afb0c41bd676f9754ffe726e18/Lib/unittest/suite.py#L115), so `setUpClass` will not be called again for the same class.