# How to print the contents of contact list when designing a new class

Tags: python

I'm learning and experimenting with Python. How can I pass the `contact_list` in my second function `print_contacts` so that it can print the name from the `contact_list`? I'm sure I am doing something wrong, can anyone please explain why is it so?

```
class Contact(object):
    contact_list = []

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        return Contact.contact_list.append(self)

# How to pass contact_list to below function?

    def print_contacts(contact_list):
        for contact in contact_list:
            print(contact.name)
```

Comment: print_contacts(Contact.contact_list), comments in python are marked with a `#` not `//`, also you need to mark the second function as a classmethod or either factor it out

Comment: __init__ methods do not return any meaningful value.  So basically you should just do `Contact.contact_list.append(self)` because `return` there does nothing useful.  And, list.append() does not return anything anyway...

Answer (score 2):

To me it doesn't make any sense to have a `Contact` object also own a `contact_list` attribute, and even less if it's class-wide instead of instanced. I would do this instead:

```
class Contact(object):
    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} <{self.email}>"
        # or "{} <{}>".format(self.name, self.email) in older versions of
        # python that don't include formatted strings


contacts = []

def print_contacts(contacts: "list of contacts") -> None:
    for c in contacts:
        print(c)

adam = Contact("Adam Smith", "adam@email.com")
contacts.append(adam)

bob = Contact("Bob Jones", "bob@email.com")
contacts.append(bob)

charlie = Contact("Charlie Doe", "charlie@email.com")
contacts.append(charlie)

print_contacts(contacts)
# Adam Smith <adam@email.com>
# Bob Jones <bob@email.com>
# Charlie Doe <charlie@email.com>
```

Or alternatively, model an `AddressBook` that knows how to create `Contact` objects and display them all.

```
class AddressBook(list):
    def add_contact(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_contact = Contact(*args, **kwargs)
        self.append(new_contact)

    def display_contacts(self):
        for contact in self:
            print(contact)

contacts = AddressBook()
contacts.add_contact("Adam Smith", "adam@email.com")
contacts.add_contact("Bob Jones", "bob@email.com")
contacts.add_contact("Charlie Doe", "charlie@email.com")
contacts.display_contacts()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Contact(object):
  contact_list = []

  def __init__(self, name, email):
      self.name = name
      self.email = email
      Contact.contact_list.append(self)

  @classmethod
  def print_contacts(cls):
      for contact in cls.contact_list:
          print(contact.name)

cont1 = Contact("John", "john@john.com")
cont2 = Contact("Mary", "mary@mary.com")
Contact.print_contacts()
```

will print

```
>>John
  Mary
```

To answer your question as to why your code currently doesn't work: first, your **init** method doesn't need a return call, **init** is called upon object creation to establish object variables and typically doesn't need to return anything (especially in this case since .append() doesn't provide anything to return).  Second, a classmethod seems better suited for what you are trying to do with the second method, and you can read more about that here: [What are Class methods in Python for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-are-class-methods-in-python-for)

Comment: `@classmethod` takes the class as the first argument. You may want to provide a full example of what your intent is with that suggestion.

Comment: If you make `print_contacts` a class method, you should implement it more cleanly. `def print_contacts(cls): for contact in cls.contact_list: print(contact.name)`

Comment: Good tip, Adam.  Thanks.