# why dict.fromkeys(keys, value) works but list.append() doesn't?

Tags: python, types, keyword

I am pretty new to python and saw that we can get a dict by `dict.fromkeys(keys, value)`, I am not sure why here you can use dict, not `dict()`.?

For list and int or str, if use this

```
list.append(1)
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-f15c629423f5> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 list.append(1)

TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'int'
```

and it doesn't work even with the list object

```
list.append([1])

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-b98586d7f7ed> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 list.append([1])

TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

if I

```
type(dict)

return type
```

what is 'type' type?

this might be a dumb question, but I could not find any answers online, anybody can help?

Comment: `dict` is a class (aka type) which creates an object of this type if using call syntax `dict()`. a class/type is itself an object of type `type`.

Comment: Unless you've overwritten the type `list` with an actual `list` object, the syntax is `list.append(L, 1)` where `L` is a list.

Answer (score 1):

[`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) is a [class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-are-class-methods-in-python-for), basically meaning it doesn't need to be attached to an instance of a `dict` class to work. This makes sense - `dict.fromkeys` is basically an alternative constructor for a dict.

[`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20append#data-structures) on the other hand is a regular instance method, meaning we need an actual `list` instance to call `.append` on. This also makes sense - appending is an operation that does not precede the creation of a list, i.e. we need a list to append to.

We can also reference instance methods as class attributes, and get back a regular function object that we pass an instance to as the first argument, i.e. `list.append(some_list, 'foo')`.

Comment: thanks,make a lot of sense now. one more question, why type(dict) return 'type' not something like 'class' or 'class name'?

Comment: @Kurt This is a bit of a tricky question, but the short answer is because `dict` is actually an instance of a `type` class, a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=metaclass#metaclasses) that creates instances of `dict`'s for us! Notice that `dict().__class__.__class__` is `type` too. This is an advanced topic in Python, a good overview is found in e-satis' answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python).