# Why Use Class Methods Instead Of Just Using The Class Name For Instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, class-method

I have a question. I am watching class tutorials and cam across class methods. My question can be better understood after seeing the code. I will show the code first.

The Code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.from_lastname()


    def from_lastname(self):
        Person.mostpreviouslastname = self.lastname

p1 = Person('Mike', 'Wizoski')
print(Person.mostpreviouslastname)
print(p1.lastname)

p2 = Person ('Indiana', 'Jones')
print(p1.lastname)
print(p2.lastname)
print(Person.mostpreviouslastname)
```

That was the part without class methods.
This is with:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        Person.from_lastname(self.lastname)


    @classmethod
    def from_lastname(cls, last_name1):
        cls.mostpreviouslastname = last_name1

p1 = Person('Mike', 'Wizoski')
print(Person.mostpreviouslastname)
print(p1.lastname)

p2 = Person ('Indiana', 'Jones')
print(p1.lastname)
print(p2.lastname)
print(Person.mostpreviouslastname)
```

They both work the same. So my question is why even use class methods at all?

Comment: Methods want to do something with an instance of a class, a classmethod wants to do something with a class itself (like use it to make an instance for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classmethods in python make more sense when you consider inheritance.  Let's use a slightly more evocative example:

Say you have a class `Item` that represents an item in your grocery store.  Let's also say that all `Item`s can come in a two-pack. We'll represent that with a classmethod that returns a tuple.

```
class Item:
    @classmethod
    def two_pack(cls):
        return cls(), cls()
```

Now let's say you want to subclass `Item` to really represent specific items, like `Soda`

```
class Soda(Item):
    pass
```

Now we can call `Soda.two_pack()` and get a tuple of `Soda` objects, even though the `two_pack` method doesn't know about `Soda` objects at all.

This also touches on the main use of class methods, which is providing alternate means of building an object, so you're not limited to what firs in `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

In your example you likely *wouldn't* want to use class methods. That's because there can only be one value of `fullname` and it's attached to the `Person` class object. So if you ever had more than one *instance* of `Person`, then they couldn't have separate `fullname` values.

In your case you'd want to remove the class method and have `from_fullname` reference `self`, so that the names are different for each `Person` instance:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.from_fullname()

    def from_fullname(self):
        self.fullname = self.lastname


p1 = Person('Mike', 'Wizoski')
p2 = Person('Bob', 'Jones')
print(p1.fullname)
print(p2.fullname)
# Wizoski
# Jones
```

If you stuck with either of your examples, you'd get the wrong result when instantiating more than one person:

```
# Jones
# Jones
```

So when would you use class methods? When you have some function that doesn't use any of the *instance's* data (i.e. doesn't need a `self` reference). More detailed explanations can be found here:

- [What are Class methods in Python for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-are-class-methods-in-python-for)
- [Difference between Class and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods)

Comment: This is not exactly what I’m looking for. I changed the question a bit to make it easier to understand. Thx, though.