# what is the use and when to use @classmethod in python?

Tags: python, class-method

I have never used @classmethod and I do not think of any examples to use it, I know how it works but I do not know when it's time to use it for example

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self,param1,param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls,param1,param2):
        return cls(param1,param2)

example = Example.my_method(1,2)
print(example)
```

output:

```
<__main__.Example object at 0x02EC57D0>
```

But why not do this?

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self,param1,param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

    def my_method(self,param1,param2):
        return Example(param1,param2)

example = Example(1,2)
method = example.my_method(3,4)
print(method)
```

output:

```
<__main__.Example object at 0x02EC57D0>
```

It's the same result but it does not come to mind when I could use classmethod

Comment: Now imagine you inherit from this class. You will always get an `Example` instance instead of one from your subclass.

Comment: Your example is a classic use of classmethods (constructors). The reason to use those instead of regular methods is that you don't have to initialize an instance to use them.

Imagine your class' `__init__` did something like open a network connection or consume some sort of resource; you wouldn't want to create an instance just to create other instances.  You could just call `Example.my_method()` without having any actual Example instances.

Also this question might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238/what-is-the-purpose-of-class-methods

Comment: @KlausD. can you please elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are 3 kinds of methods in python:

- Instance method
- Class method
- Static Method

```
class Person():
    species='homo_sapiens' # This is class variable
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name # This is instance variable
        self.age = age

    def show(self):
        print('Name: {}, age: {}.'.format(self.name, date.today().year - self.age))

    @classmethod
    def create_with_birth_year(cls, name, birth_year):
        return cls(name, date.today().year - birth_year)

    @classmethod
    def print_species(cls):
        print('species: {}'.format(cls.species))

    @staticmethod
    def get_birth_year(age):
        return date.today().year - age


class Teacher(Person):
    pass
```

1) Instance method (*show*) need an instance and must use *self* as the first parameter. It can access the instance through *self* and influence the state of an instance.

2) Class method (*create_with_birth_year* and *print_species*) need no instance and use *cls* to access the class and influence the state of a class. We can use *@classmethod* to make a factory, such as:

```
navy = Person.create_with_birth_year('Navy Cheng', 1989)
navy.show()
```

and **this factory can be inherited**:

```
zhang = Teacher.create_with_birth_year('zhang', 1980)
print(type(zhang))
```

and class method can be used access class variable:

```
Person.print_species()
```

3) Static Method (*get_birth_year*) need no special parameter(*self* or *cls*) and will change any state of a class or instance. It can privde some helper function about a class.

Comment: This was a super clear and simple way to understand the different methods - better than tutorials found online - thanks!