# Difficulty in understanding the python variable declaration

Tags: python

I am newbie to Python and trying to decode a line to port over to Go.
In the current python script, I come across this declaration (dataValue) under most of the class.

```
class Keys(object):
   AB1 = 0x0FF
   AB2 = 0x0A2
   dataValue = {'0xffff':None}

   @classmethod
   def _init(cls):
     for ke, vl in vars(cls).items():
```

1. What is dataValue? Is 0xffff a key and hold None as a value?
2. What does vars(cls).items() return?
3. @classmethod means this class keys is used only once?
   (I came across many definitions for @propoerty, @classmthods still these keywords confuses me)

Trying to understand the concepts thru real projects.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you understand `dataValue` already.  It's a dictionary.

Comment: For #3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38276/12975140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `dataValue` is a dictionary variable name, which has in it `key:value` pair of `'0xffff':None` https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html.
2. `vars(cls).items()` Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars.
3. A function returning another function, usually applied as a function transformation using the @wrapper syntax. Common examples for decorators are classmethod() and staticmethod() https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod.